# Oracle 11gR2 Enterprise manager problem

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I joined a company as a fresher DBA and in testing server there is weird problem.

My listener is running very well and developers can connect remotely to database but whenever I tried to start enterprise manager it shows me error like:

> Listener status down. The listener "(Listener name)" is not running
>   using the Listener parameter file:
>   "D:\app\dbadmin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin/listener.ora" on
>   Host: "(Hostname)" at Port: "1521".

When I write `emctl status dbconsole` it shows me:

> C:\Windows\system32>emctl status dbconsole Oracle Enterprise Manager
>   11g Database Control Release 11.2.0.1.0 Copyright (c) 1996, 2010
>   Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   https://(HOSTNAME):5500/em/console/aboutApplication Oracle Enterprise
>   Manager 11g is running.
>
> Logs are generated in directory
>   D:\app\dbadmin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1/(Hostname)_(Listenername)/sysman/log

Here is my `listener.ora` file:

```
(Listener Name) =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = (Hostname))(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

`lsnrctl status`:

```
 LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 10-JUL-2018 14:33:08

Copyright (c) 1991, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                02-JUN-2018 19:18:22
Uptime                    37 days 19 hr. 14 min. 57 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   D:\app\dbadmin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         d:\app\dbadmin\diag\tnslsnr\ESTDEV03\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=ESTDEV03)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "********" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "*******", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "******" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "******", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully.
```

`TNSPING` Result:

```
TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on 13-JUL-2018 10:16:01

Copyright (c) 1997, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
D:\app\dbadmin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = (Service Name))))
OK (20 msec)
```

`TNSNAMES.ORA` File:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\dbadmin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

(Listener Name)=
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = (service name))
    )
  )

(Listener Name) =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
```

I asked old DBA but he was not able to find a solution.
So can you please tell me where is a problem?

Comment: give us the output of "lsnrctl status" on the listener itself

Comment: @AndrewBrennan I added it in question.

Comment: OK it's not that. Might be a bug to do with windows file names - note the forward slash in the error message that isn't in the listener config

Comment: @AndrewBrennan i also noticed that, is there any way to change that slash?

Comment: Your lisetner.ora looks odd lsnrctl status shows hosts as ESTDEV03 and localhost(127.0.0;1) and yet listener.ora shows "HOSTNAME"?.Multiple instances on same host?.If muliple instance set enviornment varibales properly.Check in ORACLE_HOME  for directory either 127.0.0.1_SID or ESTDEV03_SID (SID is your %ORACLE_SID%).Let me know if that directory exists.Always set environmental variables before running emctl/emca commands(set ORACLE_UNQNAME=%ORACLE_SID% and Set ORACLE_SID=%ORACLE_SID%).

Comment: Can you post tnsnames.ora and tnsping output

Comment: @Sam I added tnsname.ora and tnsping output in question and directory named ETSDEV03_SID available in oracle_home and i also set ORACLE_UNQNAME but same output is there.

Comment: In your listener.ora is it "Hostname" or "ESTDEV03"?. Try to change localhost to ESTDEV03 in tnsnames.ora so that tnsping returns host = ESTDEV03 ,stop  and restart dbconsole(if this doesn't work execute emctl clearstate agent and restart dbconsole).Check for logs and trc files in sysman directory for clues.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the local agent:

```
> emctl stop agent

> emctl clearstate agent

> emctl start agent
```

Comment: Did it but nothing happened. It still shows an error.